# How do one notification after uploading batch of files

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, aiogram

I have a code like this

```
async def handle_docs_photo(message: types.Message):
    try:
        files = await bot.get_file(message.photo[-1].file_id)
        # await message.answer('data/' + str(message.from_user.id) + files.file_path[-12:])
        await bot.download_file_by_id(message.photo[-1].file_id,
                                      'data/' + str(message.from_user.id) + '/' + files.file_path[-12:])
        logger.info('{} {}', message.from_user.username,
                    'data/' + str(message.from_user.first_name) + '/' + files.file_path[-12:])
        await message.answer('Все сохранено', reply_markup=inkb)
    except Exception as e:
        await message.answer(f'{message.text}, {e}')
```

After processing, it issues a message

```
await message.answer('Все сохранено', reply_markup=inkb)
```

And shows the inline keyboard.
To prevent a message from popping up every time a batch of files is sent, there is an idea that I need to collect files into a list and process them in a loop.

The question is where to do this?

Answer (score 0):

As the `handle_docs_photo()` is triggered multiple times for each photo. I use this little hack of `global variable` paired with `time of trigger` to control the logic of next triggers.

```
global before
before = datetime.datetime.now()

@bot.message_handler... #your proper decorator that you didn't mention
async def handle_docs_photo(message): #your function
    global before
    now = datetime.datetime.now()

    # stuff that need to be done always.
    print(message)

    #you can adjust the timedelta to your needs
    if now - before > datetime.timedelta(seconds=5):
        # stuff that need to be done based on the consecutive triggers.
        # it executes for the first time and
        # if the time difference is >5s perform below logic.
        await message.answer('Все сохранено', reply_markup=inkb) #your msg
    before = now
```

Comment: I tried this, but did not bring the desired result.
The handler works as many times as the files are sent.
Therefore, delay is not beneficial.

Comment: Did I mention anywhere that this will be triggered only once and downloads all files? No, the handler function will be called every time and the files will be downloaded but for consecutive triggers it doesn't spam with multiple messages.

Comment: And I'm very much sure that this doesn't add any delay, if you are talking about the first time initialisation of 'before' variable, you can set different past time there. (maybe like 10 secs before or yesterday's time).